# Should i make apps for tablets and phones separately?

Tags: android-3.0-honeycomb, android

I am currently developing an android app for phones and for tablets.I need to know whether i should make a separate app for a phone and a tablet.Is there anyway of making a single app for both?

Thanks

Comment: This questions needs much more details as it is not possible to provide an answer without "it depends". What kind of app do you want to do? What layout forms do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a single app for tablet and phone unless you have a very pressing reason not to.

Since 1.5/1.6, Android has given resources to manage several different screen sizes.  All programming logic should be unaffected by the size of the screen.  Everything should be defined in layout files.

That said, if you're programming an openGL game with drastically different phone and tablet behavior, you may want to consider it.  Otherwise, stick with one app.

Comment: Btw you can upload different apks for your app on the market.

Comment: yes, that is a recent addition to the market.  Like I said, you should only do this if necessary, though.  Two codebases are always harder to maintain than one.

Comment: This is where version control comes into play.

Comment: Absolutely!  Version control, cutting branches, and that sort of thing are all important.  I am simply recommending to someone I assume is a more novice developer to avoid that unless they absolutely need it.  In short, I agree with you, but I'm trying to guide the OP away from that solution in this case.

Comment: I agree on that. Android offers many possibilities to develop uniform applications for many api levels.

Comment: @all Thanks for the reply guys.I was concerned that the app made for phone would not be able to utilise all the additional features present for the tablet such as the action bar .

Comment: this is true, and thats a choice you need to make.  you can also wrap your code so it handles different things differently for different API levels.